# Xcode 6 symbolication not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, symbolicatecrash

I've followed some of the SO solutions for symbolicating but I can't get any of the Apple framework lines to symbolicate.  Using symbolicatecrash outputs a new crash log to the terminal, but it only symbolicates my code:

/Applications/XCode6/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash crash1.crash Defqt.app.dSYM

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x185f59e48 0x185e34000 + 1203784
1                                   0x1966540e4  + 6818185444
2   CoreFoundation                  0x185f597fc 0x185e34000 + 1202172
3   Defqt                           0x1000e5358 __39-[MUTCameraAssetGroupList getAllAlbums]_block_invoke (MUTCameraAssetGroupList.m:139)
4   AssetsLibrary                   0x18528d58c 0x185284000 + 38284
5                                   0x196c993ac  + 6824760236
6                                   0x196c9936c  + 6824760172
7                                   0x196c9d980  + 6824778112
8   CoreFoundation                  0x185f116a0 0x185e34000 + 906912
9   CoreFoundation                  0x185f0f748 0x185e34000 + 898888
10  CoreFoundation                  0x185e3d1f4 0x185e34000 + 37364
11                                  0x18efd35a4  + 6693926308
12  UIKit                           0x18a76e784 0x18a6f8000 + 485252
13  Defqt                           0x1000e174c main (main.m:16)
14                                  0x196cc2a08  + 6824929800


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196ddb270 0x196dc0000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196e79224 0x196e74000 + 21028
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000196d52b14 0x196cf0000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195e39414 0x195e38000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195e58b88 0x195e38000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001966543bc 0x19664c000 + 33724
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195e55bb0 0x195e38000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195e55474 0x195e38000 + 119924
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000196654200 0x19664c000 + 33280
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f597f8 0x185e34000 + 1202168
10  Defqt                           0x00000001000e5354 __39-[MUTCameraAssetGroupList getAllAlbums]_block_invoke (MUTCameraAssetGroupList.m:139)
11  AssetsLibrary                   0x000000018528d588 0x185284000 + 38280
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196c993a8 0x196c98000 + 5032
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196c99368 0x196c98000 + 4968
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196c9d97c 0x196c98000 + 22908
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f1169c 0x185e34000 + 906908
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f0f744 0x185e34000 + 898884
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e3d1f0 0x185e34000 + 37360
18  GraphicsServices                0x000000018efd35a0 0x18efc8000 + 46496
19  UIKit                           0x000000018a76e780 0x18a6f8000 + 485248
20  Defqt                           0x00000001000e1748 main (main.m:16)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000196cc2a04 0x196cc0000 + 10756
```

I get the following errors after running the script:

```
Use of uninitialized value $image_base in hex at /Applications/XCode6/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash line 572.
Use of uninitialized value $image in sprintf at /Applications/XCode6/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash line 573.
Use of uninitialized value $image_base in sprintf at /Applications/XCode6/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash line 573.
Use of uninitialized value $image_base in hex at /Applications/XCode6/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash line 572.
Use of uninitialized value $image in sprintf at /Applications/XCode6/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash line 573.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the "symbolicatecrash -v xxx.crash" command to get the verbose log,  you should be able to find the apple frameworks' symbols could not be found,  they should be located in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/${iOS version},  the symbols will be copied if you connect a real device to your mac and synchronise it,  and the version must be exact same with the device's iOS version which the crash report occurs.

I don't know where to download the symbols for different iOS versions,  the question [Missing iOS symbols at “~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781026/missing-ios-symbols-at-library-developer-xcode-ios-devicesupport) has asked this but no answer at the moment.

Comment: I just provided an answer at the linked question. Short version: You need to connect a device running the same iOS build and supporting the same CPU architecture the crash report was created on. Connect that device to the computer so Xcode can import the symbols. Symbols for bugfix iOS versions can not be downloaded. Xcode comes with the symbols for new iOS versions which include API changes.